# How can I fix this MySQL Code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

How can I fix the following code?

```
function userExists($pdow, $login)
{
$userQuery = "SELECT * FROM login u WHERE login=:user;";
$stmt = $pdow->prepare($userQuery);
$stmt->execute(array(':user' => $login));
return !!$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$login = 'user';
$exists = userExists($pdow, $login);
if('$login')
$user= var_dump((bool) 'Exists');
{
echo "Login exsists!";
}
```

I have two problems with my code.

**First error:**
Error with echoing 'login exsists!'. I see this echo all the time in browser.

**Second error:**
When I get echo 'login exsists!' my code still inserts data to database.

Comment: maybe `if($exists){ echo "exists";}`

Comment: You can try as suggested by @devpro

Comment: When i do this i get error message : "Notice: Use of undefined constant Exists - assumed 'Exists' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDR\register.php on line 35
bool(true) Login exsists!"

Comment: do not use quotes... just `if($exists)` not `if("$exists")`

Comment: What ! {echo "exists"} !!

Comment: `echo "exist"` just a hint for success stuff. :p

Comment: @devpro not  funny !

Comment: no my friend, check Kristian Hareland update..

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
    $servername = '';
    $dbname = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$dbname}", $username, $password);


function user_exists($dbh, $Login) {
    $Q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login = :Login");
    $Q->bindParam(':Login', $Login);
    $Q->execute();
    return $Q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

//Lets try:
$user = user_exists($dbh, 'email@example.com');
if ($user) {
    echo 'User: ' . $user['login'] . ' was found in the database.';
} else {
    echo 'The user was NOT found.';
}
```

Comment: Please [don't use functions like your db()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection)

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Hmm after reading the article i have to admit i did not know, will edit answer to fit the needs and don't do it again :)

Comment: that's better. I also improved it a bit, removing unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($login)
            // this line doesnt make any sense!
            // $user= var_dump((bool) 'Exists');
            // so this is not a valid if clause
       {
           echo "Login exsists!";
       }`
```

Comment: Agreed the original code makes no sense. But you would noy want quotes around $login.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        $pdow = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=log_cdr', 'root', 'slawek132');
        $pdow -> query ('SET NAMES utf8');
        $pdow -> query ('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci');
        $pdow->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sqlw = "INSERT INTO login (login, pass, pass_v, email, email_v)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["login"]."','".$_POST["pass"]."','".$_POST["pass_v"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["email_v"]."')";

                function user_exists($login) {
                    $Q = pdow()->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login = :Login");
                    $Q->bindParam(':login', $Login);
                    $Q->execute();

                    if ($Q->rowCount() != 0) {
                        //User exist:
                        return $Q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    } else {
                        //User doesn't exist.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: almost, just copy my answer and fill in the details :)